# How to imbricate select and join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I use MySQL and JPA 1.9.4

I need to imbricate multiple join to retrieve a list of objects A with a specific object C that I can find through an object B.

Entity A: id b_id
Entity B: id c_id
Entity C: id number

Here, I want to retrieve a list of A with a C.number equals to 1 for example.

I tried to chain left join and to imbricate select table.

Example of try A-B: This one works.

```
SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.b_id = b.id;
```

Example of try B-C: This one works too.

```
SELECT * FROM B b LEFT JOIN C c ON b.c_id = c.id WHERE c.number = 1;
```

Example of try A-B-C: This one doesn't work.

I started just by trying to rename the new table from A-B and mysql says "duplicate column name 'id'"
I did several other try but I obviously have syntax issues that I don't succeed to fix myself.

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.b_id = b.id) AS a_inter;
```

To summary, I succeed to get A-B or B-C but never A-B-C table to then retrieve my list of A objects of interest.

Could you help me please?

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: you did not put the example of try A-B-C.

I guess it is like this, isn'it ? 
`SELECT * FROM A a 
LEFT JOIN B b ON a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN C c ON b.c_id = c.id 
WHERE c.number = 1;`

Comment: OMG! This is actually so simple! Thanks!!

Comment: glad to hear it is solved

Comment: please mark this post as solved

Comment: I needed an answer to mark it as solved. I posted an answer but I can mark it as solved only in two days. Thanks MattOverF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comment on top.

```
SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.b_id = b.id LEFT JOIN C c ON b.c_id = c.id WHERE c.number = 1;
```

Thanks to MattOverF.